# Rails...Am I modeling this correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application there are courses which have steps. (A user proceeds though the course by viewing the steps in order)

But there are many types of steps (Quiz, Text, Video..etc). In this example I will show 2 of the steps.

Here is my database/model design so far:

### steps

- id
- step_type_id
- client_id
- title
- summary
- position

*Relationships*:

- belongs_to: client
- belongs_to: step_type
- has_one: step_quiz
- has_one step_text

### step_quizzes

- id
- step_id
- instructions
- correct_to_pass
- retakes_allowed
- time_limit

*Relationships*:

- belongs_to: step
- has_many: quiz_questions

### step_texts

- id
- step_id
- content

*Relationships*:

- belongs_to: step

It was suggested to me before that this is a polymorphic relationship, but I guess I don't see how it is. I see it as an inheritance relationship where a sub step type inherits its basic information from the steps table. Can this be modeled differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that in this example the best approach would be to use [STI](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/03/rails-single-table-inheritance/). Polymorphic associations are better for the inverse relationship - eg. when there would be multiple things that could have the same step (courses, workshops,...).

Comment: Also sorry if I mystified you with my previous answer, I didn't have the whole picture.

Comment: But isn't the data different enough to not work well with STI. For example a text step isn't going to have a time_limit, retakes_allowed or correct_to_pass. Maybe I am just best off modeling it the way I have it.